# Search the post using get_search_form()

Tags: php

I am trying to fetch the post based on the search of the keyword , I have used the get_search_form() also created the **searchform.php** in my root folder of the theme (Child theme).

find my files **file1.php**, where I call `get_search_form`

```
<article class="blogBanner">
        <div class="caption">
            <h1>All About Travel, Food &amp; Holidays</h1>
            <h4>Experience the Change</h4>
            <div class="field">
                <?php get_search_form(); ?>     
            </div>
        </div>
</article>
```

**searchform.php** (this file is in the root folder of child theme)

```
<form role="search" name="main-search" method="get" class="search-form" action="<?php echo esc_url(home_url( '/' )); ?>">
    <input type="text" class="form-control input-search" name="s" placeholder="" value="<?php echo get_search_query() ?>" />
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-search"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
</form>
```

So whenever I search for the posts with any keyword from the form(it bringing the form searchform.php) it shows all the posts irrespective of the keyword searched.

Comment: Do you have any `pre_get_posts` filters? Are you using a custom search.php that implements its own search function, maybe?

Comment: @janh I am not using any filters neither I have search.php , Its wokring fine , if I activate parent theme but then in child theme it lists all the posts irrespective of the keyword searched.